# java de-compiler plugin URL for eclipse galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse galileo. I want to add java decompiler to my eclipse. I tried multiple URLs but they are not compatible with galileo.

Please share the decompiler URL location for Eclipse galileo.

Thanks,
Anil Kumar C

Comment: try this link. it works for me. http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update

Comment: @Jameelopix You should write an answer

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr) JD-GUI for sometime, which is a standalone application, they do have an [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) version. You could try it out if you like. The tool is quite basic but does what it's supposed to.